# How to get notification for firebase test lab results?

Tags: android, automated-tests, firebase-test-lab

I use jenkins to build and upload apk to firebase test lab, I use async method.

Is there anyway to get notification for test pass or fail for this async tests, say web hook or mail?

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly the answer you're looking for, but it is worth noting that Firebase Test Lab can now send a notification email when your test is complete if you initiated the test from the Firebase Console UI. Unfortunately that feature does not currently work with the `gcloud` CLI. To enable these notification emails, surf to https://firebase.corp.google.com/subscriptions/project/your-project-id (also reachable from the ... menu in Test Lab) and check the `Email` box next to "A console test run has completed."

If you still need a notification feature for `gcloud --async`, please submit a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).